# TikZ - How can I align a node by a line which is a path?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to horizontally align a rectangle with several nodes in it with a rectangle with several nodes. The rectangles are above one another. When I boil down the code to a *minimal* example, the following MWE comes out.

As far as I know, I pretty much followed the bits on pages 39, 138 and many others in the manual. Basically, I don't get it. Why doesn't it work?

### MWE, which does not work

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
\draw
(0,0) coordinate (cornerSW)
(10,0) coordinate (cornerSE)
(10,3) coordinate (cornerNE)
;
\draw[name path=something] (cornerSW) rectangle (cornerNE);
\draw[name path=aaa] (cornerSW) -- (cornerSE) node[midway, above] {aaa};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm, below=of aaa.south, anchor=north]
\node[fill=red!20] at (2,0) {Test};
\end{scope}
\draw[fill=red] (aaa) circle [radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### Update MWE after Percusse's first comment

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    intersections
    }

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
\draw
(0,0) coordinate (cornerSW)
(10,0) coordinate (cornerSE)
(10,3) coordinate (cornerNE)
;
\draw[name path=something] (cornerSW) rectangle (cornerNE);
\draw (cornerSW) -- (cornerSE) node[midway, above] {aaa};
\draw ($(cornerSE)!0.5!(cornerSW)$) coordinate (aaa);
\node[fill=red!20, below=of aaa, anchor=north] {Test};
\draw[fill=red] (aaa) circle [radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are referring to a path but you need to refer to coordinates or nodes.

Comment: Hm, tried it with it with `\draw ($(cornerSE)!0.5!(cornerSW)$) coordinate (aaa);` -> Updated the op. The node doesn't work either, the red circle is good.

Comment: `\draw (aaa) coordinate ($(cornerSE)!0.5!(cornerSW)$);`?

Comment: You can also draw the rectangle using \path (0,0) node[draw=black,above right,text width=10cm, text height=3cm,inner sep=0pt] (aaa) {}; in which case (aaa.south) etc. would be defined.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well it certainly works, just not aligning the `scope` below it. That is a bit annoying and I think I'll work on something else for now.

Comment: @cfr That is not work the right syntax, but thank you.

Comment: @percusse Hm, tried it with it with `\draw ($(cornerSE)!0.5!(cornerSW)$) coordinate (aaa);` -> Updated the op. The node doesn't work either, the red circle is good. Aligning of a scope does not work like that apparently. Would be so handy though if it did.

Comment: Scopes are not nodes; they don't have anchors and you can't use all of the same options.  xshift, yshift and rotate are about it.  But you can achieve the same effect using relative coordinates.

Comment: For the updated code, you still need the `positioning` from tikzlibrary. BTW, do you need the `intersections` library?

Comment: @Jesse Sorry, a remnant of the original code, so it's more like something I don't actually need in the MWE.

Comment: Everyone, I made some errors along the way in my original code and it was all a bit silly in the end. I solved it by increasing the minimum width of the upper rectangle and addressing its lower middle point via a new coordinate. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @henry if you found a solution, have you thought about writing a self-answer so your efforts are useful to future visitors? Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: @PaulGessler Will try to find that solution and will report back.

Comment: @PaulGessler Can't find the actual solution to the problem above anymore, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `fit` library does just what you need.

I made your `corner<cardinal>` coordinates into nodes just so it's easier to see what's going on, but a node can be fit to nodes *or* coordinates, it doesn't matter.

The node named `fitted` contains all of the objects that should take part in the centering, and then the "Test" node can be positioned relative to the `fitted` node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
(0,0) node (cornerSW) {SW}
(5,0) node (cornerSE) {SE}
(5,3) node (cornerNE) {NE}
(8,2) node (test) {test}
;
\node[draw,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,fit=(cornerSW) (cornerSE) (cornerNE) (test)] (fitted) {};
\node[fill=red!20, below=of fitted, anchor=north] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Removing `(test)` from the fit, we can see that "Test" re-centers itself with respect to the remaining fit items:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
(0,0) node (cornerSW) {SW}
(5,0) node (cornerSE) {SE}
(5,3) node (cornerNE) {NE}
(8,2) node (test) {test}
;
\node[draw,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,fit=(cornerSW) (cornerSE) (cornerNE)] (fitted) {};
\node[fill=red!20, below=of fitted, anchor=north] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]